# Separating object by toon shading

Tags: modeling, toon-shading

How to slice a mesh based on "constant color ramp" as defined below into three objects?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that with the diffuse BSDF node before the color ramp.

One way to do something close is by removing the diffuse BSDR node and adding a group of Texture Coordinate+Mapping+Separate XYZ nodes:
[image]

This way, you can fix the axis chosen for slicing the object (Z axis in this example).

Then you can create 2 cutter cubes which will be positioned in that axis with both drivers, one per color ramp stop:

Select the second stop in color ramp, right click on its value and select *Copy as new driver*:

[image]

[image]

Select the first cutter cube, right click on its location Z value and select *Paste driver*:

[image]

Then edit the driver by selecting Scripted expression and in Expression multiply the position var by the Z size of your object (2m in this example):
[image]

The first cutter cube is now placed over that color separation and will follow that step value when editing:

[image]

Repeat this steps for the second cutter cube linked to the last step of the color ramp.

After that, make 2 copies of your object and set the following boolean modifiers to them:

- Original object:
  [image]
- Copy 1:
  [image]
- Copy 2:
  [image]